# Led pot light wire damaged at rough in by drywall cutout tool. How to repair?

Tags: electrical

Looking for advice on what to do here.

Surprisingly the light works fine even though it appears a lot of the individual wires in the stranded wire are cut.

[image: led pot light wire]

[image]

120v 35w is the max rating of the fixture so line voltage.  The bulbs are led.  I might have a spare fixture lying around that i could pull a virgin connector out of.

Comment: Ouch. How on earth did that happen?

Comment: Can you shoot us a photo looking down into where that wire goes into the light itself at?

Comment: Will do. This is a bayonette style connector for the bulb, I believe the wire goes through the porcelin and attaches to a female receptor for the circular portion of the bayonete on the bulb but I'll get another shot looking down on it tomorrow.

Comment: I suppose the drywallers didn't have the depth on their cutout tool adjusted and plunged the cutter too far into the housing.  I typically see the depth gauge is the first thing to fall off cutout tools and then depending on how well the ele has pushed the wires into the box or if the wires have fallen down the drywaller nicks them.  This wasn't the only one...  in a normal box however you typically just have wires which can be shortened if damaged like this.  The ele either didn't see the damage or didn't care and just pushed it back up into the housing.

Comment: if the wire isn't warm after running the light for an hour, just tape it all up.

Comment: Is this a mains voltage or low voltage fixture?  And how expensive would it be to just replace the fixture?  I ask because while repair is probably possible, A) it might void the fixture's UL listing, and B) it's very possible that sourcing a new matching socket would not be much cheaper than just getting a whole new fixture.

Comment: Dandavis, that's a truly bad suggestion. Someone puts in a higher-wattage bulb or further degradation occurs due to flex and things get smoky.

Comment: 120v 35w is the max rating of the fixture so line voltage.  The bulbs are led.

Comment: The reason it works, incidentally, is because 35W/120V = 0.29 A, which is extremely tiny.  The *remaining* wire I'd estimate to be somewhere between 24 and 30AWG, and even 30AWG is good for half an amp.  However, it still needs to be replaced for the reasons isherwood mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My non-code, unofficial, somewhat hackish, minimally risky solution would be to:

1. Cut the wire as long as possible near the socket base. You'll need at least 3/4" of good wire.
2. Cut the wire at an undamaged point on the other side of the damage.
3. Strip both wires 3/8" and twist well (but not so vigorously that you damage it).
4. Install a butt-splice connector of appropriate size with a good crimp.
5. Wrap the repair with tape, then *wrap the other wire in with it* to create a splint to prevent pullout. Use a high-heat tape as this is a tight space with heat-resistant insulation on the wires.

Comment: It's a good idea, but I don't think there's 3/4" of wire available there.  Looks more like 1/4 or 3/8 at most, and I don't think that'd be enough to crimp onto with most butt splices I've used.  I think it might be necessary to replace the lamp socket.

Comment: Maybe. If you count the tail of wire currently hanging out of the jacket, and if there's a bit of slack to be had in the socket....

Comment: If there's slack, yeah, maybe, but I think with that type of socket, there's not going to be -- the wire is probably crimped to the contact.  You're right though that there's a couple mm already out of the insulation I wasn't counting, but I'm not sure if that's the full wire thickness, or if there are other strands broken off below the insulation that we can't see.

Comment: I think have I have a spare fixture kicking around that I can pull the connector from with more wire.  It would be a lot of work to pull open the drywall replace fixture, patch drywall, mud, sand, prime, and then try to feather in matching paint.

Comment: For the connection between the two braided wires I've seen where people expand the brands, butterfly them, and then ferule crimp them - though that was low volt.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k2q28V46s5w  1:41 to 2:00.  Would this style of ferule connector work?  I haven't done a butt connector on line voltage before can I use a butt connector from an automotive connector kit?

Comment: For high heat tape are you thinking something like:  https://www.amazon.com/Scotch-Super-Vinyl-Electrical-Tape/dp/B00004WCCL/ref=sr_1_6?keywords=high+heat+electrical+tape&qid=1578970452&sr=8-6

Comment: I don't have specific product recommendations to offer. Any solid crimp with reasonable insulation should do.